# Changing order of expectation for a double expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I have an equation with two expectations, which looks like the follows:

\begin{align}
   E_{o} E_{z} (\sum_{i=1}^{m} f_1(o_i) * f_2(z_i)) \\ 
\end{align}

Where $o$ is a discrete random variable with finite number of states, and $z$ is a continuous random variable.

Now my question is, can I swap the order of the expectation, i.e. take expectation w.r.t $z$ first, then w.r.t $o$ ? Is the following assumption valid?

\begin{align}
   E_{o} E_{z} (\sum_{i=1}^{m} f_1(o_i) * f_2(z_i)) = E_{z} E_{o} (\sum_{i=1}^{m} f_1(o_i) * f_2(z_i))
\end{align}

My end goal is to move expectation w.r.t. $o$ inside the summation with $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you can exchange integrals is a matter of [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) and its various close associates. The short answer is that it depends on your function $f$ and the distribution of the random variable $z$.

Two conditions you might check, either of which would be sufficient to guarantee that you can exchange the integrals:

1. Is $f$ nonnegative?
2. Assuming a no on the above -- that is, $f$ has negative values -- is $E_0 E_z \left(  \left| \sum_{i=1}^m f(o_i) * f(z_i) \right| \right)$ finite?

For checking condition 2, the sum being finite and $o_i$ being finitely supported means that everything rests on the mapping of $f(z_i)$. If $f(z_i)$ is bounded, for instance, then you're fine.

Failing that, things get more technical; the counterexamples on the linked Wikipedia article may be illuminating.

Comment: Thank you, Aaron, for your reply. I was checking the form of my equation again and I think I made a mistake. I have two functions, one dependent on $o$ and the other one on $z$. The first function (of $o$) is an indicator function and the second function (of $z$) is basically a parameterized log-likelihood function, with a neural network with a softmax layer at the end. Softmax can give close to zero value if the input is very large, in that case, log-likelihood can be close to infinity.

Comment: Happy to help. I won't pretend to understand all the details of what you've said, but you might be in good shape -- if $f$ is really just a log-likelihood, then perhaps it's non**positive**, which is just as good as nonnegative for Fubini's Theorem purposes. (Proof: Negate it.) The only concerning case would be if $f(z_i)$ can assume *both* large positive *and* large negative values.